# Что я не так делаю с сокетами?

Tags: android, сокет

код на Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(7475);
    System.out.print(serverSocket.getInetAddress()+"  "+ serverSocket.getLocalPort());
    Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.print("DA");
    socket.close();
}
```

Код в андроид

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7475);
                    client.setSoTimeout(100);
                    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("asd");
                    dataOutputStream.flush();
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                    client.close();

                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "1");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "3");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

В итоге я получаю Error 1, блин порт прослушивается, вбивал через netstup, незнаю уже что делать, антивирусник отключал, все бестолку, Андроид на Ginemotyion

Comment: На компьютере запускаете Java сокет, а с Android'а пытаетесь приконектиться к нему?

Comment: Да все верно, но не работает

Comment: IP у сервере 0.0.0.0./0.0.0.0. Ну по сути правильно он же слушает не IP а порт

Comment: @xTIGRx, 127.0.0.1 - это же ip андроида? и куда вы цепляетесь? к андроиду? а оно вам надо? ip компа нужен

Comment: IP Компа? локалхост чтоли, я даже внешний IP пробовал. На 2ip брал, тоже без результатов

Comment: @xTIGRx внешний IP лежит за натом. Вы через него и так не сможете приконектиться никогда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас Android пытается соединиться к локалхосту  `Socket("127.0.0.1", 7475);`, то есть, к `7475` порту на Android'е.

Чтоб присоединиться к компьютеру, где сокет поднят, посмотрите в настройках сети компьютера его ip в локальной сети и присоединяйтесь к нему.

Это, конечно, при условии, что и PC, и Android в одной локальной сети.

Comment: да заработало, странно почему локалхост не работал, и внешний IP

Comment: @xTIGRx, во первых, не факт, что у вас выделенный IP. Во вторых, не факт, что вы провесили порт 7475 на роутере на свой комп.

Comment: @xTIGRx локалхост - это адрес на локальной машине. Внешний ip у вас лежит за nat'ом.